# How to clear interval function of one component from another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Parent Component**

```
handleSubmitValidateInput: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {phone: this._phone.value, pwd: this._pwd.value}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data:data,
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
        success: function(data){
            ReactDOM.render(<Home UserDetails={data}/>, document.getElementById('content'));
            var idleTime = 0;
            var interval = setInterval(function(){
                      // some code
                });
            }, (1000));
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('Error login!!');
        }
    });
},
```

I want to clear the `interval` from the **Home** component. How can I achieve this? Please explain this to me. The function below is of the **Home** component. 
I want to clear the interval from logout function.

```
handleLogout: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Cleared');
    localStorage.clear();
    ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('content'));
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a local variable, try using the `window` object.

```
window.interval = setInterval(function(){
  // some code
});
```

Then you can clear it from your logout function

```
handleLogout: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  clearTimeout(window.timeout);
  console.log('Cleared');
  localStorage.clear();
  ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('content'));
},
```

There are of course other ways of implementing this, if you'd rather not use the `window` object. This should be the shortest/easiest way however.

---

A simple Demo can be found [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/2rhuhxpb/) or in the snippet below. Check the console for output.

```js
var Start = React.createClass({
  start: function() {
    console.log("Timeout started")
    window.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Timeout ended")
    }, 2000);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <button onClick={this.start}>Set Timeout</button>;
  }
});

var Stop = React.createClass({
  stop: function() {
    clearTimeout(window.timeout);
    console.log("Timeout cleared");
  },
  render: function() {
    return <button onClick={this.stop}>Clear Timeout</button>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
   <Start />
    <Stop />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```